# What is the simplification of sum of $i(i+1)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation

I am trying to simplify $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)}{n(n-1)}$$.

I am not sure how to simplify ${\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)}$ part.

How can I simplify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may know the wellknown results $$ \sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
and 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6},$$
from which you can combine your sum.

Answer (score 1):

$i(i+1) = 2{{i+1} \choose 2}$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n {{i+1}\choose 2} = {{n+2}\choose 3}$, because ${{n+2}\choose 3} - {{n+1}\choose 3} = {{n+1}\choose 2}$ by Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution comes from

$$(i+1)^3-i^3=3i^2+3i+1=3i(i+1)+1$$

Thus

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)^3-i^3=\left( 3 \sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1) \right)+n \,.$$

The left hand side sum is telescopic.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2&=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\\
\sum_{k=1}^n k&=\frac{n(n+1)}2\end{align*}$$